# Is this formula for interior product correct?

Tags: differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space and $\omega \in \Lambda^kV^*$ a (decomposable) $k$-covector. Furthermore let $v = v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_l \in \Lambda^lV$ be any $l$-vector. Define the interior multiplication $i_v: \Lambda^k V^* \to \Lambda^{k-l} V^*$ with the $l$-vector $v$ as the linear map such that
$$
i_v \omega = (i_{v_l} \circ \dots \circ i_{v_1}) \omega.
$$
where $i_{v_i}$ is the usual interior product. If I take $\omega$ decomposable, i.e. $\omega = f^1\wedge\dots\wedge f^k$, where $f^i \in V^*$ and $k \ge l$, then I have this formula, which I ask about its correctness
\begin{align}
i_{v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_l} (f^1\wedge\dots\wedge f^k)
&= \sum_{\pi\in S(l,k-l)} \text{sgn}\pi f^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge f^{i_l} (v_1,\dots, v_l) f^{j_1}\wedge\dots\wedge f^{j_{k-l}} \\
&= \epsilon_{I,J} f^{I} (v_1,\dots, v_l) f^{J}
\end{align}
where $S(l,k-l)$ is the set of shuffles, i.e. $\pi: (1,\dots,k) \mapsto (i_1,\dots,i_l,j_1,\dots, j_{k-l}) \equiv (I,J)$ such that $i_1<\dots< i_l$, and $j_1<\dots< j_{k-l}$, and $\text{sgn}\pi$ is the sign of the permutation. The wedge product is defined here as
$$
\omega \wedge \eta = \sum_{\pi\in S(k,l)} \text{sgn}\pi(\omega \otimes \eta) \circ \pi= \frac{1}{k! l!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}} (-1)^\sigma (\omega \otimes \eta) \circ \sigma.
$$

---

**Update:**

The way I arrived to this formula is by writing any permutation $\sigma \in S_k$ as product of a shuffle followed by two permutations, each of which permutes one of the sets of indices ($i$s or with $j$s). I denote such factorisation as
$$
\sigma = \pi_{\kappa,\rho}:(1,...,k) \mapsto (i_{\kappa 1},\dots,i_{\kappa l},j_{\rho 1},\dots, j_{\rho(k-l)})
$$
where $\pi$ is a shuffle as abobe (see the quoted part in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4530571/is-this-a-correct-way-to-factorise-the-symmetric-group) and the suggested generalisation).

> The idea of writing any permutation as a shuffle followed by two permutations, each of which ...(as above), I justify it as follows, its purpose is to group the terms in the long sum in a smart way, namely, in each group we have only terms whose first $l$ factors (in the tensor product) are same up to a permutation (also the last $k-l$ terms are the same up to permutation.) The terms in each group then arise from the same shuffle followed by two permutations. Therefore each group, upon summing over the last two permutations (following the shuffle) gives wedge products. And it remains to sum over the shuffles, and that's the remaining sum in the formula

With this I rewrite the definition
\begin{align}
i_{v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_l} (f^1\wedge\dots\wedge f^k)
  &=i_{v_l}\circ\dots\circ  i_{v_1} \left(\sum_{\sigma \in S_k} \text{sgn} \sigma f^{\sigma 1}\otimes\dots\otimes  f^{\sigma k}\right)\\
  &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} \text{sgn} \sigma f^{\sigma 1}(v_1)\dots f^{\sigma l}(v_l)f^{\sigma (l+1)}\otimes\dots\otimes  f^{\sigma k} \\
  &= 
  \sum_{
   \substack{
    \pi  \in S(l,k-l),\\
    \kappa\in S_l,\\
    \rho\in S_{k-l}
   }
  } \text{sgn} \pi\ \text{sgn} \kappa f^{i_{\kappa1}}(v_1)\dots f^{i_{\kappa l}}(v_l)\ \text{sgn} \rho f^{j_{\rho 1}}\otimes\dots\otimes  f^{j_{\rho(k-l)}}\\
  &= \sum_{\pi \in S(l,k-l)} \text{sgn}\pi (f^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge  f^{i_l})(v_1,\dots, v_l) f^{j_1}\wedge\dots\wedge  f^{j_{k-l}}
\end{align}

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846171/mtws-gravitation-factor-of-contraction-of-p-vector-with-p-form) (see pglpm's amswer there).

Comment: Didn't find anything relevant

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with some of your notation, but your formula looks right. Another way to write it is
$$i_v(\omega)=\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_l}(-1)^{\sum_{j=1}^l(i_j-j)}\langle v,f^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge f^{i_l}\rangle f^{i_{l+1}}\wedge\cdots\wedge f^{i_k}$$
where $i_{l+1}<\cdots<i_k$ is the complementary ordered $(k-l)$-tuple and the angle brackets denote the scalar product between $\bigwedge^l V$ and $\bigwedge^l V^*$.

For a reference see Greub *Multilinear Algebra*, 2nd. ed. Problem 5.14.6.

Comment: Hello @blargoner, as I said I updated and clarified how I arrive to this formula. Could you give it a look

Comment: @Physor The derivation you added looks plausible in spirit but I'm not sure about factorial factors that arise from (i) definition of wedge product, (ii) definition of insertion operator, (iii) conversion between shuffles and arbitrary permutations. I suspect under the definitions you're using they probably all end up cancelling out so you're still landing at the right formula, but I've been burned by errors of this sort in other books etc.

Comment: I added somthing, but I don't know what "insertion function" you mean. Also there are no factorials needed at all

Comment: @Physor In (i) and (iii) I was referring to the factorials that appear in the second, but not the first, equality in your definition of wedge product. That convention is not universal. In (ii) I was referring to interior product, which is also called insertion operator.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I don't know where there are needed at all. The deinition of the wedge of covectors needs no such factorials, these cancel with those of the alternation (antisymmetrisor) or whatever you may call it

Comment: @Physor I'm not saying they're needed. I was just saying your argument looks right but I hadn't verified in detail that the conventions used in all your definitions are all compatible with each other. Since you're landing in the right place they probably are. I've seen other folks mix incompatible definitions using different conventions (for wedge, alternator, insertion operator, etc.) without realizing it, resulting in error, that's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, and sorry for interruption if I caused any